# How can i set TO address at runtime with log4j2 SMTPAppender

Tags: java, log4j2, smtpappender

I'm converting a simple java healthcheck application we use from using log4j1 to log4j2-17.2. It currently uses a custom SMTPAppender which extends the built in one to set **subject** and **To address** at runtime from values in the logged event.

In log4j2 can't do that as the SMTPAppender plugin class is final. Have got it working using the built in one for subject using a ThreadContext lookup, but that doesn't work for TO address and struggling to find anyway to set the To address that works.

This is what I have so far

For subject the SMTPAppender config is:

```
<SMTP   name="ErrorMail"
                subject="$${ctx:subject:-Int HealthCheck Error}" 
                to="user@company.com" 
                from="support@company.com"
                smtpHost="ldnsmtp" 
                smtpPort="25" 
                bufferSize="2000" 
                ignoreExceptions="true">
                <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <EmailLoggerLayout />               
          </SMTP>
```

With this code setting the subject then logging the event. This works and the subject appears in the email OK

```
            if (healthCheckAlert.getSubject() != null) {
                ThreadContext.put("subject", subjectPrefix + healthCheckAlert.getSubject());
            }
            warningSender.log(level, message);
```

For the To address I'm trying this to use a ThreadContext variable in same way:

```
         <SMTP  name="WarningMail" 
                subject="$${ctx:subject:-Int HealthCheck Warning}"
                to="$${ctx:mailto}" 
                from="support@company.com"
                smtpHost="ldnsmtp" 
                smtpPort="25" 
                bufferSize="2000" 
                ignoreExceptions="true">
                <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/> 
                <EmailLoggerLayout />               
         </SMTP>
```

With this code to set it:

```
        if (healthCheckAlert.getMailTo() != null) {
            ThreadContext.put("mailto", healthCheckAlert.getMailTo());
        }
```

But get the error below, which indicates it hasn't been expanded

```
2023-01-05 12:40:25,951 main ERROR SmtpManager SMTP:${ctx:mailto}:::support@company.com::${ctx:subject:-Int HealthCheck Warning}:smtp:ldnsmtp:25:::INFO Could not set SmtpAppender message options: javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Local address contains illegal character in string ``${ctx:mailto}'' javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Local address contains illegal character in string ``${ctx:mailto}''
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.checkAddress(InternetAddress.java:1216)
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(InternetAddress.java:1091)
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(InternetAddress.java:633)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.MimeMessageBuilder.parseAddresses(MimeMessageBuilder.java:99)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.MimeMessageBuilder.setRecipients(MimeMessageBuilder.java:66)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.createMimeMessage(SmtpManager.java:71)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.connect(SmtpManager.java:340)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.sendEvents(SmtpManager.java:172)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SmtpAppender.append(SmtpAppender.java:353)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:633)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:616)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:552)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:82)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2205)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2142)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:1994)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1852)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.log(AbstractLogger.java:1642)
    at com.company.utils.healthcheck.logging.EmailLogger.log(EmailLogger.java:42)
    at com.company.utils.healthcheck.EmailLoggerTest.testWarnAlert(EmailLoggerTest.java:42)
```

Have done a lot of searching to find a way to do this to no avail. Can anyone let me know if this can be done with the ThreadContext lookup somehow, or is that just not possible in log4j2 for the TO address? If so any clues on some other way to do this?.

My current backstop idea is to make our own copy of the SMTPAppender class using the log4j2 source code and modify that, but would rather not.

**UPDATE: The stacked trace when trying Piotr's idea to use a routing appender is:**

```
2023-01-17 11:46:23,815 main ERROR SmtpManager SMTP:${ctx:mailto}:::LondonIntegrationRtB@standardbank.com::${ctx:subject:-Int HealthCheck Warning}:smtp:ldnsmtp:25:::INFO Could not set SmtpAppender message options: javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Local address contains illegal character in string ``${ctx:mailto}'' javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Local address contains illegal character in string ``${ctx:mailto}''
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.checkAddress(InternetAddress.java:1216)
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(InternetAddress.java:1091)
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(InternetAddress.java:633)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.MimeMessageBuilder.parseAddresses(MimeMessageBuilder.java:99)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.MimeMessageBuilder.setRecipients(MimeMessageBuilder.java:66)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.createMimeMessage(SmtpManager.java:71)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.connect(SmtpManager.java:340)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.sendEvents(SmtpManager.java:172)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SmtpAppender.append(SmtpAppender.java:353)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.routing.RoutingAppender.append(RoutingAppender.java:243)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:633)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:616)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:552)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:82)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2205)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2142)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:1994)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1852)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.log(AbstractLogger.java:1642)
    at com.standardbank.utils.healthcheck.logging.EmailLogger.log(EmailLogger.java:42)
    at com.standardbank.utils.healthcheck.EmailLoggerTest.testWarnAlert(EmailLoggerTest.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

LogEvent message class = class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.MutableLogEventMessage parameters = [Ljava.lang.Object;@408d971b2023-01-17 11:46:23,849 main ERROR SmtpManager SMTP:${ctx:mailto}:::LondonIntegrationRtB@standardbank.com::${ctx:subject:-Int HealthCheck Warning}:smtp:ldnsmtp:25:::INFO Caught exception while sending e-mail notification.: java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.sendMultipartMessage(SmtpManager.java:287)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.sendEvents(SmtpManager.java:189)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SmtpAppender.append(SmtpAppender.java:353)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.routing.RoutingAppender.append(RoutingAppender.java:243)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:633)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:616)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:552)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:82)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2205)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2142)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:1994)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1852)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.log(AbstractLogger.java:1642)
    at com.standardbank.utils.healthcheck.logging.EmailLogger.log(EmailLogger.java:42)
    at com.standardbank.utils.healthcheck.EmailLoggerTest.testWarnAlert(EmailLoggerTest.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

2023-01-17 11:46:23,852 main ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender WarningMail org.apache.logging.log4j.LoggingException: Error occurred while sending email
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.sendEvents(SmtpManager.java:192)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SmtpAppender.append(SmtpAppender.java:353)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.routing.RoutingAppender.append(RoutingAppender.java:243)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:633)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:616)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:552)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:82)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2205)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2142)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:1994)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1852)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.log(AbstractLogger.java:1642)
    at com.standardbank.utils.healthcheck.logging.EmailLogger.log(EmailLogger.java:42)
    at com.standardbank.utils.healthcheck.EmailLoggerTest.testWarnAlert(EmailLoggerTest.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.sendMultipartMessage(SmtpManager.java:287)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.sendEvents(SmtpManager.java:189)
    ... 46 more
```

Comment: Can you explain what kind of logic did you use to select a recipient address? Allowing the recipient to be chosen at runtime from user generated data would be a security risk.

Comment: it's not from user generated data. It's from config for an alert that is raised and logged. This is a long standing process using log4j1, so just trying to get it converted to log4j2 instead to bring it up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SMTPAppender` only evaluates the subject of an e-mail as a [pattern](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#Patterns). The remaining fields are immutable.

What you can do is to use [`RoutingAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) to create a different SMTP appender per e-mail recipient. Something like this should work (I didn't test it):

```xml
<Routing name="Routing">
  <Routes pattern="$${ctx:mailto}">
    <Route>
         <SMTP  name="WarningMail-${ctx:mailto}" 
                subject="$${ctx:subject:-Int HealthCheck Warning}"
                to="${ctx:mailto:-root@example.com}" 
                from="support@company.com"
                smtpHost="ldnsmtp" 
                smtpPort="25" 
                bufferSize="2000" 
                ignoreExceptions="true">
                <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/> 
                <EmailLoggerLayout />               
         </SMTP>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
  <IdlePurgePolicy timeToLive="15" timeUnit="minutes"/>
</Routing>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've given that a try, but no joy,. Still get the same error , so seems the embedded SMTP appender still doesn't  expand the to address when it is created by the routingappender.

Comment: @dethorpe: Sorry, I forgot to set a unique name for each appender. Also the `to` parameter should have a default value.

Comment: Thanks, that's done it and working now. Bit convoluted, but does the job. Might switch to just sending the emails directly rather than via log4j2 for simplicity , but good to know the routingAppender option can work if we need it to keep it this way.